# How to simplify sympy equation?

Tags: python, sympy

Consider this simple matrix equation:

```
from sympy import *

c_a, s_a = symbols('c_a s_a')
k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, k_5, k_6 = symbols('k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4 k_5 k_6')
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')

equation = Eq(MatrixSymbol('R',4,4), Matrix([
[     c_a*k_1 - k_1 + 1, -c_a*k_4 + k_4 - s_a*z, -c_a*k_5 + k_5 + s_a*y,         0],
[-c_a*k_4 + k_4 + s_a*z,      c_a*k_2 - k_2 + 1, -c_a*k_6 + k_6 - s_a*x,         0],
[-c_a*k_5 + k_5 - s_a*y, -c_a*k_6 + k_6 + s_a*x,      c_a*k_3 - k_3 + 1,         0],
[                     0,                      0,                      0, c_a + s_a]]))
```

I've tried to simplify for a while with no success... as you can see there is a lot of possible factorizations (ie: `k_1*(c_a-1), k_4(1-c_a), ...`). I've tried many of the existing available methods sympy has to simplify https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html but no luck... factor, simplify, collect, applyfuncs(factor), simplifiy(force=True) etc.

I'm a newbie with sympy so probably there is some obvious way to simplify further these type of equations, if it's so, how?

Also, I'm just interested to simplify the `rhs` of the equation, not the `lhs`. Is it possible to simplify any of them or both?

Comment: Maybe more of a math problem?

Comment: I came here, and was like, huh, I'll try to answer! Then I saw the equation and freaked out ;-)

Comment: @Torxed At first I thought if it'd be for math stack exchange site but then i decided it was not. This is about me not being able to use properly sympy... which i'm pretty much sure it can be solve this simple problem with no sweat... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a DIY case. Something like the following may work for you:

```
>>> def most_collect(eq):
...     f = eq.free_symbols
...     if not f: return eq
...     F = sorted(f, key=lambda x: eq.count(x))
...     return collect(eq, F[-1])
>>> equation.rhs.applyfunc(most_collect)
Matrix([
[    k_1*(c_a - 1) + 1, k_4*(1 - c_a) - s_a*z, k_5*(1 - c_a) + s_a*y,         0],
[k_4*(1 - c_a) + s_a*z,     k_2*(c_a - 1) + 1, k_6*(1 - c_a) - s_a*x,         0],
[k_5*(1 - c_a) - s_a*y, k_6*(1 - c_a) + s_a*x,     k_3*(c_a - 1) + 1,         0],
[                    0,                     0,                     0, c_a + s_a]])
```

Comment: Thanks sir! Really nice answer, it sure does work for me... btw, i assume you're a sympy ninja so... may i ask when you decide it's a good time to go the `DIY` case? As a sympy newbie i started by using simplify (which i read was using some heuristics) and then just using the builtin functions... For this simple formula it was obvious we could do better for more complex ones... how do you know you didn't get the best out of sympy? Btw... offtopic question but, is there any easy way to extract the available symbols from one equation?

Comment: A matrix is a collection of expressions and in your case each had a pattern -- a symbol appearing in more than one term -- that did not involve the same symbol each time. So it's not a "generic" situation. You know you didn't get the best when you don't like what you got ;-)

As for extracting available symbols: see the function's use of `eq.free_symbols`; that attribute gives a set of all non-bound symbols used.